# See if children of movieclip on stage

Tags: actionscript-3

I am creating a platformer with as3 and need to see if children of the movieclip _boundaries are on the stage or not, that way I can remove them and lower the counter so that more will continually generate. So far all I have is below. Please help, been stuck on this for a couple of weeks.

```
var ObjectArray:Array = [];
var ChildrenColliding:Boolean = false;
var onStageCount:Number = 0;
function generateObjects():void{    
    if(_vx > 0 && onStageCount < 20){
        var Square:MovieClip;
        Square = new mcSquare();
        Square.x = Math.random() * 1000 + (Math.abs(_boundaries.x) + 50);
        Square.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight/2.5 + (stage.stageHeight/2.5);
        ObjectArray.push(Square);
        _boundaries.addChild(Square);
        onStageCount += 1;
    }
    for(var i in ObjectArray){
        Square[i] = Square.name;
        for(var a in ObjectArray){
            if(ObjectArray[i].hitTestObject(ObjectArray[a]) && a != i){ChildrenColliding = true;}
            while(ChildrenColliding){
            ObjectArray[i].x += (ObjectArray[a].height + 25);
            ObjectArray[i].y += (ObjectArray[a].width + 25);
            ChildrenColliding = false;
                if(ObjectArray[a].hitTestObject(ObjectArray[i]) && a != i){ChildrenColliding = true;}
            }
        }
    }
    //CHECK TO SEE IF CHILDREN ARE ON STAGE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    for(var w in ObjectArray){
        if(_boundaries){
            onStageCount -= 1;
            trace("removed");
            _boundaries.removeChild(ObjectArray[w]);
            ObjectArray.splice(w, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "on stage" do you mean that the instance of Square has been added to the stage, or that its coordinates (x,y) are within the boundaries of the stage?

Comment: That its coordinates are within the boundaries of the stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use the `localToGlobal` method to determine the position of the Square Objects. Something like:

```
for (var w in ObjectArray) {
    if (_boundaries) {
        var sq:MovieClip = ObjectArray[w];
        var pnt:Point = _boundaries.localToGlobal(new Point(sq.x, sq.y));
        if (pnt.x <= 0 || pnt.x >= _boundaries.stage.stageWidth || 
            pnt.y <= 0 || pnt.y >= _boundaries.stage.stageHeight) {

            // remove square
            onStageCount -= 1;
            trace("removed");
            _boundaries.removeChild(ObjectArray[w]);
            ObjectArray.splice(w, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

On a side note for general best practice, reserve words starting with capital letters for class names (like MovieClip, Sprite, or MyCustomClass) and use camelCase for variable names. It's helpful when working with other devs to promote best practice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so freaking much man. This has literally been troubling me for weeks. This solution works flawlessly

Comment: Hey now, I'm noticing an issue with the second set of for loops, the ones that deal with the childrencollding, what this causes is the objects to sort of randomly regenerate as the player is moving. Any idea on how to get the code to only make sure that the one it is placing is not colliding and to move that ones coordinates and then show it, not have all of them sort of randomly re spawn and whatnot

Comment: It's hard to say from your description. Maybe try incrementing the x,y of the target object by an integer like 1 or 2 rather than incrementing by width/height of the tested object. Also, you seem to be incrementing x by height and y by width...that logic seems reversed to me. You may want to consider a more complex logic because this will alway push the object down and to the right...even if the target object is mostly to the upper-left of the tested object. Make sense?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice and ya, it does always do that, so I will consider some complicated logic. Again thank you so much for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//CHECK TO SEE IF CHILDREN ARE ON STAGE!!!!!!!!!!
for(var w in ObjectArray){
    if(_boundaries && _boundaries.contains(ObjectArray[w])){
        onStageCount -= 1;
        trace("removed");
        _boundaries.removeChild(ObjectArray[w]);
        ObjectArray.splice(w, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: that works, it sees if they are on stage, but I guess what I am trying to do is see if the child, square, is not on stage so I can remove it and regenerate it somewhere

Comment: Hmmm... not sure if I understand the problem. If the object is not a child of `_boundaries` but exists in the array you can just use it (add as a child) elsewhere.

Comment: The object are children of movieclip _boundaries and I am trying to see if individual objects are behind the player so that i only have fifty objects around the player.